# tag 's:property value= does not show the expected message

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

The first time I call this action:

```
private long eventID = 0;
public String getUserInfo() {
    eventID = 558;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

in the jsp page, in javascript :

```
var event_id = '<s:property value="event_id" />';
```

Here `event_id` is 558.

Then I call another action which is not `getUserInfo()`. But back to jsp, in javascript:

```
var event_id = '<s:property value="event_id" />';
```

here `event_id` still is 558. It is incorrect. I can not figure out why.

Comment: Let's see your full class.

Answer (score 1):

Your action class should have getter and setter of `eventID`.

```
private long eventID = 0;
public String getUserInfo() {
    eventID = 558;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

In the jsp page:

```
 <s:property value="eventId" />;
```

for storing in js variable:

```
 var event_id = <s:property value="event_id" />;
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: @Charles In action there is `private long eventID` so how you will access that field in jsp page

Comment: Then you should say that as part of your answer.  Don't just provide a fix, provide a reason the fix works.

Comment: Nothing, it's perfect!  Okay.  Almost perfect.

Comment: @manishSahu *What is wrong with above answer?* This answer doesn't answer the question why *event_id still is 558*.